# How to auto convert a string to URL in angular 2+

Tags: angular, url

I am using Angular and I have a text field with value like:

```
text1 www.google.com test2
```

But I would like to convert it to a URL if it is a link. Like this:

> text1 [www.google.com](https://example.com) test2

the result is that there is a text field value , if there is any of string can detect as url , then convert the string to be a url

Answer (score 0):

If you want a result like this :

```
text1 <a href='www.google.com'>www.google.com</a> test2
```

You can do something like :

```
const strArray = 'text1 www.google.com test2'.split(' ');
strArray[1] = `<a href="${strArray[1]}">${strArray[1]}</a>`
const newString = strArray.join(' ');
```

Comment: no that simple , I want the result is that when the text field with url , then auto conver it to a link which can click on